# Django form: subsetting a ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a way to filter a multiple choice field in django forms such that one will see only a specific portion of the user database.

I have three models:

- a research results model (named `Forskningsresultater`);
- a user model (the default `User` model); and
- a custom-made M2M model between the first two models (named `PersonRes`). This custom-made M2M model has been imported using Django Import/Export.

Say that I have a model with 300 users and that one particular research result has 5 authors. In the form, I want to display checkboxes for only these 5 authors instead of all 300. The checkboxes are used to change the `participant` field in the `PersonRes` model (see the `models.py` box below). Therefore, I want to:

1. Subset so only authors related to a specific research result through the M2M model are shown.
2. Even though a user unchecks an author as a participant (so that we have four checked authors and one unchecked), it should be able to go back to this form and still see all authors (here: all five authors) and make additional changes to all these authors if needed.

## models.py

```
class Forskningsresultater(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='PersonRes', blank=True,related_name='authors',verbose_name="Authors")

class PersonRes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,verbose_name="user")
    forskningsresultater = models.ForeignKey(Forskningsresultater,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,verbose_name="forskningsresultater")
    participant = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class ForskningsresultaterApproveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    authors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,queryset=User.objects,label="Participants",widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta():
        model = Forskningsresultater
        fields = ('authors')
        widgets = {
        }
```

I suspect I should use `.objects.filter(...)` in the form's `queryset`, but I haven't found a functioning way to do it yet.

Comment: The default value part of the linked answer isn't relevant to you, but the demonstration of modifying the field's queryset in `__init__` is.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the duplicate – I wonder why I didn't find this when I googled this.

May I ask you for help once more? Using your link, I found a solution that works: `authors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,queryset=User.objects.filter(personres__forskningsresultater=902040),label="Participants",help_text='',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)`. However, look at `902040` in the code. This is the pk for the specific instance I'm working on and this will thus only work for pk=902040. But I want Django to fetch this pk automatically so it works for all instances.

Comment: You'd want to get the user in the view and pass it as an arg to the form constructor. The point is not to put it in the class definition, but rather the change the field's queryset after instantiating it.